# Dynamic Kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, angular-kendo, kendo-ui-grid

I am facing an issue with the dynamically created kendo UI grid. 
When I specify the the columns array with **`title`** and **`field`** properties and render the grid, the grid columns do not show the specified **`title`** instead they show the **`field`** name. I do not want the field name to show up as it is, cause the field name itself will not make sense as a column header.

Note: This is done inside an angular controller.

This is my grid definition

`<div kendo-grid="ctrl.commonGrid" options="ctrl.commonGridOptions"></div>`

Here is the code that I use to generate the columns.

`var columns = [];`

`angular.forEach(ctrl.ColumnConfig, function (col) {
                    var newCol ={
                        title: col.displayName,
                        field: col.mappingProperty.toCamelCase(),
                    }
                    columns.push(newCol);
                });`

After this I assign this to the grid columns collection

`ctrl.commonGridOptions = {
                    columns: columns,
                };`

and then just use the grid dataSource data method to populate the data.

`ctrl.commonGrid.dataSource.data(ctrl.TableData);`

I am scratching my head since yesterday, but not able to figure out whats going wrong.

Can anyone help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed this. Following is the code that works as expected. The firstRow is nothing but the row from the list of objects that I fetch from the server, and the columnConfig is the configuration of the columns I want to display.

`for (var property in firstRow) {
                    if (firstRow.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                        model.fields[property] = { type: 'string' };
                        var col = $.grep(ctrl.columnConfig, function (e) { return e.mappingProperty === property });
                        if (col.length) {
                            columns.push({
                                title: col[0].displayName,
                                field: col[0].mappingProperty
                            });
                        } 
                    }
                }`